# Смешивание `background-color` дочернего элемента с `background-image` родительского элемента с помощью CSS

Tags: css, css3, html5, background

Я хочу смешать цвет фона элемента с фоновым изображением родительского элемента. 
Если для свойства css `background-blend-mode` установлено значение `multiply`, оно будет работать только в том случае, если цвет и изображение установлены для одного и того же элемента.

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
}

.mixit-green {
  background-color: #ddffdd;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  padding: 50px;
}

.mixit-blue {
  background-color: #ddddff;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="mixit-green"></div>
  <div class="mixit-blue"></div>
</div>
```

Но я хочу использовать разные цвета, смешанные на одном и том же фоновом изображении, поэтому мне придется смешивать фоновое изображение с цветами детей. Есть ли способ добраться туда?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56689227/7394871

Answer (score 2):

это `mix-blend-mode`, а не `background-blend-mode`<sup>1</sup>

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
}

.mixit-green {
  background-color: #ddffdd;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  padding: 50px;
}

.mixit-blue {
  background-color: #ddddff;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="mixit-green"></div>
  <div class="mixit-blue"></div>
</div>
```

`background-blend-mode` используется при наличии нескольких фонов. Таким образом, вы можете изменить ответ выше, как показано в примере ниже:

```css
.bg {
  padding:100px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(#ddffdd 50%,#ddddff 0),
  url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAAwCAYAAABXAvmHAAABhGlDQ1BJQ0MgcHJvZmlsZQAAKJF9kT1Iw0AcxV9TtSIVBzuIOGSoThb8KOKoVShChVArtOpgcumH0KQhSXFxFFwLDn4sVh1cnHV1cBUEwQ8QF1cnRRcp8X9JoUWMB8f9eHfvcfcOEOplplkdY4Cm22Y6mRCzuRUx9IouRBBGHOMys4xZSUrBd3zdI8DXuxjP8j/35+hV8xYDAiLxDDNMm3ideGrTNjjvE0dYSVaJz4lHTbog8SPXFY/fOBddFnhmxMyk54gjxGKxjZU2ZiVTI44TR1VNp3wh67HKeYuzVq6y5j35C8N5fXmJ6zSHkMQCFiFBhIIqNlCGjRitOikW0rSf8PEPun6JXAq5NsDIMY8KNMiuH/wPfndrFSYnvKRwAuh8cZyPYSC0CzRqjvN97DiNEyD4DFzpLX+lDkx/kl5radEjoG8buLhuacoecLkDDDwZsim7UpCmUCgA72f0TTmg/xboWfV6a+7j9AHIUFepG+DgEBgpUvaaz7u723v790yzvx/Ct3LHCx725AAAAAlwSFlzAAAuIwAALiMBeKU/dgAAAGxJREFUaN7t1bEJwDAMBVE5ZBLtv5K8itKatC4Sw/udUHVwcKOqOpZl5nrGnDP+/L/i8AH4eqO7+yTn338KAdjcfZrzOgBAB3QAgA5QCIAOUAiADlAIgA5QCIAOUAiADlAIgA5QCIAOUAjA1h7zMO7kJjvXlwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
</div>
```

> <sup>1</sup> Определяет `blending mode` **каждого фонового слоя**.
>
> Каждый фоновый слой должен смешиваться с фоновым слоем элемента,
> который находится под ним, и цветом фона элемента.
> **Фоновые слои не должны смешиваться с содержимым, которое находится за элементом**, вместо этого они должны действовать так, как будто они
> отображаются в изолированной группе. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#background-blend-mode)</sup>